# Free Marker: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I use freemarker templates and i have given the code within the ftl file below.

```
<#if (actionErrors?exists && actionErrors?size > 0)>
    <ul>
    <#list actionErrors as error>
        <li><span<#rt/>
<#if parameters.cssClass?exists>
 class="${parameters.cssClass?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#if parameters.cssStyle?exists>
 style="${parameters.cssStyle?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
>${error}</span></li>
    </#list>
    </ul>
</#if>
```

The above code gives the following error.

> freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression error is
>   undefined on line 33

I wrapped the ${error} with <#if error.value??> and tried again. Still it gave the same issue. Then i used the ${error.value!'N/A'} as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577482/freemarkers-skip-assertnonnull-invalidreferenceexception). Still it didn't resolve the issue. Please help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, the `error` value appears not to have been set.  When you do this:

```
${error.value!"Default"}
```

...you are providing a default in case the `value` attribute of `error` is not set. It still assumes that `error` is set so that it can get the `value` attribute off it.  If you do this:

```
${(error.value)!"Default"}
```

...the default will apply if *either* `error` or `error.value` is not set.  The parentheses say "apply the default to the enclosed expression."  If Freemarker encounters a missing value anywhere while parsing the enclosed expression, it applies the default.

This also works with the `??` operator:

```
<#if (error.value)??>The entire expression error.value is valid</#if>
```