# freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException

Tags: struts2, freemarker

FreeMarker template error!

```
Expression activity.activityId is undefined on line 47, column 19 in 
   WEB-INF/planning/activitiesList.ftl.
```

The problematic instruction:

```
${activity.activityId} [on line 47, column 17 in WEB-INF/planning/activitiesList.ftl]
in user-directive activityList.activitiesList [on line 72, column 11 in WEB-INF/planning/activities.ftl]
```

Stacktrace:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression activity.activityId is undefined on line 47, column 19 in WEB-INF/planning/activitiesList.ftl.
at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:118)
at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:167)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:428)
at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:172)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:614)
at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:259)
at org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerResult.doExecute(FreemarkerResult.java:215)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
at
```

Comment: What are you asking? Do you have a problem? What is it.

Comment: Yes i have problem while working struts2 integration with freemarker templet,it is showing error like,                                                   Expression activity.activityId is undefined on line 47, column 19 in 
   WEB-INF/planning/activitiesList.ftl

Comment: Why didn't you define this variable? Post a source code.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577482/freemarkers-skip-assertnonnull-invalidreferenceexception?